# what are good prototyping tools for Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am looking for some tools that I can design Lightning Experience prototypes in.

Comment: Can't answer directly as some mods are zealots, but there's a Lightning Component pack for probably the most popular design tool - Sketch App: https://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/2795-salesforce-design-system-template-sketch-freebie-resource.html

Answer (score 7):

A colleague likes [MockFlow WireframePro](https://blog.mockflow.com/wireframepro-new-ui-pack-for-salesforce-lightning-design-system-27875) - good for people who do not have HTML/CSS skills.

For people with HTML/CSS skills there is the [Design System UI Kit and Starter Kit](http://sfdcworkshop.com/workshop/rapid-prototyping-with-slds/).

Comment: I've tried WireFramePro now and I agree with you, it's very easy to use and setup, great tool for getting started with mockups and prototypes.

Comment: The second link does not work anymore.